# datamigration from oracle to mysql using grails

Tags: grails, datasource, grails-orm

I am new to grails programming .My requirement is to migrate data from Oracle to Mysql not through a tool but using an Grails application. How can I achieve this ..any suggestions ??. Can I change the datasource in Controller so  that I can fetch the data using one datasource and save the object in another datasource

Comment: IMHO this approach is not a very good one. Grails is a framework for web application but not to migrate data from a dbms to another dbms. Why don't you use a database migration application?

Comment: I agree with @saw303. Why do you need the extra bloat? You could use Groovy for this task though. Really simple and fun. ;)